# How to convert my Array of data to key & value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array like this.

```
My Array= PartnerNumber,1044,FirstName,rob,Rank,302
```

I would like it to be represented as key and value pair

```
[1]Partner Number - 1044
[2]First Name - rob
[3] rank -302
```

I would need to post this array data and form a query on my server side control.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with? Do you know what a `for` loop is, which you can use to iterate over the array? Do you know what an object is? If not, I suggest to read a tutorial first: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Answer (score 4):

In modern Web browsers, you can use the very useful [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function:

```
var array = ["PartnerNumber",1044,"FirstName","rob","Rank",302];

var dictionary = {};

array.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if(index % 2 === 0) {
       dictionary[item] = array[index + 1];
    }
});

document.write("Partner number:" + dictionary.PartnerNumber);
```

Try it on jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/6DZvb/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a=["PartnerNumber",1044,"FirstName","rob","Rank",302];
var object={};
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i+=2)
{
    object[a[i]]=a[i+1];
}
```

Then you can access it like,

```
object["PartnerNumber"]
object["FirstName"]
object["Rank"]
```

Comment: `object` is a reserved keyword

Comment: It is not.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: Ok, it's not reserved. Anyway, I wouldn't use this identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
var arr=['PartnerNumber',1044,'FirstName','rob','Rank',302];
var newArr={};
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i+=2) {
    newArr[arr[i]]=(arr[i+1]);
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: would this be performance enhacement over the assignment solution?

Comment: I get this in Chrome: Array[6] 
0: "PartnerNumber",
1: 1044,
2: "FirstName",
3: "rob",
4: "Rank",
5: 302. I think it is not pushing in the expected way

Answer (score 0):

```
obj={};

for(i=0; i<arr.length-1; i=i+2){
   obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
}
```

now if your array is,

```
arr=[key1,value1,key2,value2,key3,value3];
```

you will get a new object as,

`obj = {key1:value,key2:value2,key3:value3}`;

Answer (score 0):

Check this working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/AsrmBZaShXDGny6ZHreq?p=preview).
Is this what you want? If you open up the console, it will display:

```
Object { Partner Number: 1044,  First Name: "rob",  Rank: 302}
```

EDIT: added code in comment

```
var myArray = ["PartnerNumber", 1044, "FirstName", "rob", "Rank", 302],
    myObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
  if (i % 2 === 0)
    myObj[myArray[i].replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(',', '')] = myArray[i + 1];
}

console.log(myObj);
```